# Несколько COUNT в одном запросе

Tags: php, mysqli

Нужно посчитать количество записей в таблице `users`, где `action` равен 0, 1, 2, 3

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query('запрос')) 
                    { 
                        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
                        {
```

Чтобы потом через функцию использовать `$row['count1']...`

Answer (score 6):

Если прямо так, как вы хотите, одной записью, то:

```
select sum(if(action=0,1,0)) count0,
       sum(if(action=1,1,0)) count1,
       sum(if(action=2,1,0)) count2,
       sum(if(action=3,1,0)) count3
  from table
```

Либо:

```
select action,count(1)
  from table
 where action between 0 and 3
 group by action
```

На выходе из 4х получившихся записей с количествами собрать массив значений самому либо использовать функции PDO для выборки готового массива с требуемой структурой

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE action = 0 OR action = 1 OR action = 2 OR action = 3 ');

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

или можно сразу

```
"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE action = 0 OR action = 1 OR action = 2 OR action = 3;"
```