# Вытащить статистику одним запросом за последнюю неделю и месяц

Tags: mysql

Казалось бы простая задача, но уже пол дня не могу решить. Вытащить количество записей за последний месяц и последнюю неделю для каждого пользователя.

Логи пользователя хранятся в **user_log**. И если для месяца и недели можно вытащить ограничив выборку и посчитав количество. Как это сделать одним запросом? Только через подзапрос? Или понедельник мне дался тяжело?

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.email,
    COUNT(*) as monthly
FROM user_log ul
    LEFT JOIN `user` u ON u.user_id = ul.user_id
WHERE ul.added_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY u.email
```

Структура таблиц проста

```
CREATE TABLE `user_log` (
    `user_log_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `added_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_log_id`),
    INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`),
    INDEX `added_date` (`added_date`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `u` (`email`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Как нибудь так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508889/194569 , например. только условия внутри sum сделать на основе дат что бы брать за неделю. а в where взять все записи за месяц

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.email,
    SUM(ul.added_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) as monthly,
    SUM(ul.added_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) as weekly
FROM user_log ul
    LEFT JOIN `user` u ON u.user_id = ul.user_id
GROUP BY u.email
```

Comment: Спасибо! За SUM не подумал, почему-то вцепился в COUNT

Comment: Я бы предложил все таки ограничить месяц в where и соответственно первый sum() заменить на count(). А то когда БД будет за 10 лет пробегаться по всем записям для подсчета месяца как то не очень

Comment: @Mike С точки зрения производительности два подзапроса вообще выглядят намного перспективнее одного запроса, хоть с дополнительным WHERE, хоть без. Но коли автору охота экономить на спичках - его дело. Равно как мне непонятно желание группировать по user.email, а не по user_log.user_id.